# Brace-enclosed initializer for matrix constructor fail in type std::complex<double> >

Tags: c++, c++11, complex-numbers, list-initialization

I implented a contructor for my matrix class to do brace-enclosed initialization using nested std::initializer_list. The constructor works fine for primary type: `int`, `double`; but renders error-reading for `complex`. How to fix this error reading?

The matrix class

```
template <typename T> class xxx
{
 public:
     T *ptr;
     int col, row, size;
     xxx() = delete;
     xxx(const int i, const int j):row(i), col(j), size(i*j)
     {
         ptr = new T [this->size] ;
     }
     xxx(const std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<T> > s):xxx(s.size(), s.begin()->size())
     {
       int j = 0;
       for (const auto& i : s) {  std::copy (i.begin(), i.end(), ptr + j*col); ++j ; }
    }
    ~xxx() {delete [] this->ptr;}
     T operator()(const int i, const int j) const { return ptr[i*col+j]; }
};
```

A typical ouput overload is added here for complete.

```
template <typename X> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&p, const xxx<X>&a)
{
    for (int i=0; i<a.row; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j <a.col; j++) p << std::setw(6) << a(i, j);
        p << std::endl;
    }
    return p;
}
```

The first test main() with type `double` works well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
int main()
{
    xxx<double> x = {{1, 2,3,4} , {3, 4,5,6}, {5, 6,7,8} };
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

It prints what is expected:

```
$ ./a.exe
     1     2     3     4
     3     4     5     6
     5     6     7     8
```

Then, I try with another type of my interested, `complex`:

```
int main()
{
    xxx< std::complex<double> > z = { {(1,2), (3,4)}, {(5,6), (7,8)} };
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

The outpur is wrong as follows:

```
$ ./a.exe
 (2,0) (4,0)
 (6,0) (8,0)
```

The imaginery part is missing, and the real parts are taking values of the counter imaginery part. Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post a [mcve] please? Without your `operator<<` I cannot see output from the code

Comment: output overload is added for completebess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the initializer list. The problem is that this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> x = (1,2);
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Is not doing what you expect it to do. Output is

```
(2,0)
```

Because `(1,2)` is the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) at work. `std::complex<double> x = (1,2);` is the same as `std::complex<double> x = 2;`.

You need to use curly braces for initialization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> x = {1,2};
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Output

```
(1,2)
```

*PS* I would strongly advise you to use a `std::vector<T>` to hold the data rather than a `T*`. Currently copying a `xxx` will cause undefined behavior, due to not following the rule of 3/5.

Comment: @largest-prime-is-463035818 Thank you. The (real, imah) is comventional format in file i/o for complex number. I am too mush used to the parathesis form. For numerucal worker aiming at  at a natrix about 500x500, the std::vector is not a pratical choice, I did have a matrix class for Hermitian and sysmetric eigen probelm in c99, and try to update with some newer language protocol,

Comment: @ytlu "the std::vector is not a pratical choice" why do you think so? If a `T*` can do it then a `std::vector` can do it as well.

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 For example, to copy a large matrix, one will do memory copy instead of element to element assignment. I wonder if you can savely perform memory copy in a std::vector structure?

Comment: @ytlu yes you can. When I said "If a `T*` can do it then a `std::vector` can do it as well" then I meant exactly that ;)

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 You may do it with iterator? but for matrix person, the concern is in the speed of element fetching, therefore, will try to compact the data as  possible. Other methods of flexibility is definitly not in considerations.

Comment: @ytlu using a dynamic array via `T*` is not any more compact than a `std::vector`. It is also not slower/faster per se. A `std::vector<T>` basically *is*  a `T*` plus exactly the code you need to write if you want to use a `T*` properly.

Comment: @ytlu I am not talking about a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` in case thats the misunderstanding. Nested vectors really have severe downsides

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 I see. Using std::vector<T> to provide the core bonn for the memroy piece. I need some experience to build my confidence level with it. Thank you for helping, save my time, very appreciated,